# How post a message on main thread with Kotlin Multiplatform (Desktop)?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I have computation which run on threads, and sometimes, I want to post a message on main thread to update some data used in UI.

On Android, I do it with a code like this:

```
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper

val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

fun PostMessageToMainThread() {
    mainHandler.post(Runnable {
        println("Print from main thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}")
    })
}
```

But on KMM Kotlin Multiplatform mobile (with Compose Multiplatform), I cannot find solution to do this. Note that for the moment, I'm looking for code which work on Android and Desktop (iOS will handle later).

Note that I try coroutine, but I'm not able to use `Dispatcher.Main` (I have a runtime exception which tell that `Dispatcher.Main` is not available), even when adding `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-swing:1.7.2")`).

Is there any multiplatform way to post a message to main/UI thread with Kotlin?

Comment: I'm curious about why you (think you) need this. I've written quite a few Compose Desktop applications already, and I've never needed an explicit dispatch to main/ui thread.

Comment: I have a backend in C++ which compute data from USB (HDMI stream using OTG) and sometimes depending on the computation, I have to update my UI to display. When it happens C++ call a kotlin function (from a C++ thread) and at this point, the safe way to update data/UI I know, is to send a message on main/UI thread to update data value (that will automatically update the compose UI).

Comment: And you're sure just updating from any thread doesn't work? It usually does, but I'm not sure if JNI changes anything.

Comment: I just start the implementation, so I don't really know. But even if it works now, I need to be sure it's thread safe to avoid futur bug... I try to find official documentation about thread safe and `State` (or `mutableStateListOf`), but for the moment, I found nothing certain. If you have information about that, do not hesitate to share it. Indeed, it would be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

With Compose, you don't need to do that. You can simply update your `State` objects from any thread.

However, if you really still want to, you can add [kotlinx-coroutines-swing](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-swing/) and use `Dispatchers.Main`. Alternatively, you can use `org.jetbrains.skiko.MainUIDispatcher`, which says in its javadoc that it uses the Swing event dispatching thread.

Comment: Does the Compose for Desktop use Swing underneath? I guess not, I believe it draws the UI using Skia. In that case I think it doesn't make sense to suggest using the Swing main thread as it won't be the same main thread as for the UI framework.

Comment: It uses Swing for stuff like the window, I believe. But even if it doesn't make sense to you, it's what the library authors recommend, so....

Comment: Regarding updating State from any thread, I was not aware it was thread safe. I will check that `mutableStateListOf` is thread safe too. For coroutines-swing, I try to used it, but I have an exception when accessing to `Dispatchers.Main`. I'm a beginner in gradle/kotlin, so perhaps there is something I missed when adding `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-swing:1.7.2")` to my gradle file

Comment: @Jorn Ok, if Compose docs suggest to use Swing's main dispatcher then my comment is irrelevant.